# preloader another swf with preloader

Tags: flash, preloader, actionscript-3, fla

I need to open "game.swf"

Before i opened with this swf, called "loadgame.swf" (downloaded from the website of the game, flashgame.com/loadgame.swf)

```
        this.Chargeur = new Loader();
        Security.allowDomain("*");
        this._C._B.width = 1;//this part of the loading animation
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.Chargement_Ok);//this part of the preloader
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this.Chargement_EnCours);//this part of the preloader
        addChild(this.Chargeur);
        this.Chargeur.load(new URLRequest("flashgame.com/game.swf"));
        return;


    public function Chargement_Ok(event:Event) : void
    {
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.Chargement_Ok);//this part of the preloader
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this.Chargement_EnCours);//this part of the preloader
        this.Charge = 0;//this part of the preloader
        this.pregame = DisplayObject(this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.content);                  //This is part of additional functions that I put in the game
        Loader(this.pregame.getChildAt(0)).contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.gameInserido);   //This is part of additional functions that I put in the game
        this.BtcPlugin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.Funcgame);                  //This is part of additional functions that I put in the game
        removeChild(this._C);//this part of the loading animation
        return;
    }// end function
```

I wore this loadgame.swf directly from my pc to access the game....Currently the game does not accept it anymore.

However I can access the game this way:

```
        this.Chargeur = new Loader();
        Security.allowDomain("*");
        this._C._B.width = 1;//this part of the loading animation
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.Chargement_Ok);//this part of the preloader
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this.Chargement_EnCours);//this part of the preloader
        addChild(this.Chargeur);
        this.Chargeur.load(new URLRequest("flashgame.com/loadgame.swf")); //(the online version it loads game.swf, but without the additional functions)
        return;

    public function Chargement_Ok(event:Event) : void
    {
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.Chargement_Ok);//this part of the preloader
        this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this.Chargement_EnCours);//this part of the preloader
        this.Charge = 0;//this part of the preloader
        this.pregame = DisplayObject(this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.content);                  //stopped working
        Loader(this.pregame.getChildAt(0)).contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.gameInserido);   //stopped working
        this.BtcPlugin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.Funcgame);                  //stopped working
        removeChild(this._C);//this part of the loading animation
        return;
    }// end function
```

By accessing "http://www.flashgame.com/loadgame.swf", I'm accessing a copy of my "loadgame.swf" but without the additional functions.

Well actually I need,

```
this.Chargeur.load(new URLRequest("flashgame.com/loadgame.swf"));   
//(game.swf will be open within that swf)
this.Chargeur.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.Chargement_Ok);
//(Load only when Chargeur open game.swf completely)
```

If someone is willing to help I thank...

Answer (score 0):

Your application domain could be the problem.

try like this:

```
var _urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(“mySecondarySwf.swf”);
var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
_loader.load(_urlRequest, _lc);
```